Finding mimimum value through inequality
Question
$a,b,c$ are positive real numbers. $a+b+c=3$
Find the minimum value of $$\frac{a}{6-a}+\frac{b}{6-b}+\frac{c}{6-c}$$
My attempt
I tried using Arithmetic mean $>$ Geometric mean and Cauchy inequality but did not get anywhere.
However, I understood that $a=b=c=1$ will give minimum due to symmetry. But I need proof of this. Any help would be appreciated.
For context, this is a high school problem.

This question is similar to: Let $x,y,z>0$ and $x+y+z=1$, then find the least value of ${{x}\over {2-x}}+{{y}\over {2-y}}+{{z}\over {2-z}}$. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Found through using an ...

(cont.) Approach0 search. Note your problem is basically the same as the duplicate one, but with all of the $3$ values each multiplied by $3$. Thus, such as determined in the currently accepted answer there, your minimum would be $3\times\frac{3}{5}=\frac{9}{5}$, at $a=b=c=3\times\frac{1}{3}=1$, as you suggested. Note there are also other duplicates on this site, such as ...

(cont.) minimum value of $\frac{x}{2-x}+\frac{y}{2-y}+\frac{z}{2-z}$ is, which is what the Approach0 search actually found, with this being closed as a duplicate of my proposed duplicate of your question. There's also the AoPS thread mini value, but it doesn't currently have any solutions.

In my earlier comment, I forgot to add the link to the duplicate question's accepted answer. It is here.

One other mistake is that the minimum value doesn't change due to the scaling being the same for the numerator and denominator in the fractions. Thus, the minimum is $\frac{3}{5}$, not $3\times\frac{3}{5}=\frac{9}{5}$ as I suggested in an earlier comment.
